# The correct way to use function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

I know that the compiler automatically dereferences functions pointers.

Assume `int (*function) (int arg);`

Then `(*function)` is the same as function. But why is `&function` also the same as function? I don't understand why the following code works.

What is the correct way of passing function pointers?
When we declare a function, for example, `int f(int a)`, does it mean `f` is automatically the address in which the function is stored?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int cmp (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(int*)a-*(int*)b;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i; 
    int A[5] = {0,2,3,1,4};
    qsort(A, 5, sizeof(*A), cmp);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d,",A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    qsort(A, 5, sizeof(*A), &cmp);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d,",A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    qsort(A, 5, sizeof(*A), *cmp);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d,",A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Neo C++ has both. You can still use `printf` in C++.

Comment: @Neo C++ is not compatible with C, but the code posted here is valid C++.

Comment: It's **not** compatible. This code happens to work *as C++* as well, as far as I can see. Still this question doesn't seem to relate to C++ at all, so tag removed.

Comment: "*Then (*function) is the same as function.*" you should explain what you mean here. Also, `qsort(A, 5, sizeof(*A), *cmp);` should be a compile error, you can't dereference a function (`cmp`).

Comment: @FelixPalmen Of course you can dereference a function. It's just like you can dereference an array.

Comment: @melpomene you're right on that one (well, not exactly like arrays, but nevermind). Still, don't spam unrelated tags.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Don't remove relevant tags. This is a valid C++ question.

Comment: @Chuanyuan should clarify if the question refers to C or C++. It could be either one.

Comment: Your premise is faulty, if `int (*function) (int arg)`, then `&function` is not the same as `function`.

Comment: @melpomene it's not, community concensus is that a question needs to be about interfacing C and C++ or a direct comparison to qualify for **both** tags. This code is C style and doesn't mention anything about C++, so it's a C question, EOD.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Should I edit the tags from linked OP? It has a `std::cout` call and has tags as C++ and C.

Comment: @Amadeus no, we shouldn't touch ages-old questions IMHO. Nowadays you would ask for clarification first (if any doubts arise like clearly mixing C and C++ concepts) to avoid this kind of tag-spam.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Well, clearly the community is wrong on this one.

Comment: @melpomene that's your opinion, a majority is in favor of avoiding unnecessary tags. There are corner cases, but with code that doesn't show a trace of typical C++, the tag is wrong and probably the result of too many people not being aware there's a difference.